# CSS Media Query for Samsung Galaxy Note II

Tags: css, media, media-queries, samsung-mobile

Can someone help me telling me which is the best way to target a Samsung Galaxy Note II with CSS Media Queries? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Aim to target the screen resolution - that way your rules will apply to multiple devices, rather than you having to target dozens of different devices.

Answer (score 0):

You don't usually target a specific device. Instead you specify rules for the viewport width or the device width. The first step is to make sure your html is set up properly.

#### Doctype & Viewport

I know without specifying the doctype the `window` element in javascript doesn't get an inner width. That would mess up media queries in css so specify it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Add a microsoft-specific tag meaning "most recent everything" with regard to following W3C specs. Otherwise windows phone browsers might screw things up.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Finally make sure you have a correct viewport meta tag. For example [according to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_II) the Galaxy Note II has `3 subpixels/pixel`. This would mean the page would render 3x as wide as the screen and the user would only see 1/3 of the page at a time and need to scroll horizontall.

The following meta tag in the `<head>` fixes this problem.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

The above is all part of [HTML 5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/). When in doubt start there.

#### Media Queries

In your CSS you can specify media queries based on the width and height of the device. Usually you only care about width, but you can tailor rules to device width and height as well.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    /* rules here */
    .sidebar { display: none; }
}
```

Rules in media queries in my experience have precedence. There's a [CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) on device sizes to get started.

#### Web Inspector

To test if it works, the Chrome and Firefox dev tools both have emulators for popular devices. For example in Chrome, open the dev tools and click the phone icon.

[image: chrome web inspector button]

Then choose the device you want and play with the css queries till it looks good.

[image: chrome web inspector galaxy note]

I've cut off the image, but the header is clearly rendered correctly.